# Redmine plugin application-wide permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, permissions, redmine

I'm writing a plugin for Redmine 2.0.1. While I have most of the requirements already fulfilled, I'm struggling with the permissions for the plugin.

The plugin itself is "global" in terms of Redmine, i. e. it project-independent. Is there any Redmine-instance-wide permissions system, or just the project-related permissions system?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It lasted quite a long time, but I finally managed to find a solution. If you're interested, here's what I did.

1) Create new model with the boolean permissions that you need
2) Create a User patch, so that User model now has the permissions. Example is [here](https://gist.github.com/3780802)
3) Update the user edit template, so that it contains the custom permission
4) Use the permission anywhere you like.

HTH